# Simple stringifying using << operator

Tags: c++, beginner, unit-testing, formatting, io

**Background**

I wrote `my_length` class and some code. `my_length` can be stringified using `<<` operator, and `main()` tests this.

**Questions**

1. I think `operator<<` can be refactored. How can I rewrite `operator<<` of `my_length`, and make it better code?
2. How can I make rest of code better?

**Code**

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>

class my_length {
  int id;
  std::string name;
  uint64_t v;     // unit is 'mm'
  bool fmt_auto;

  public:
  my_length (int id, std::string name, uint64_t v)
    : id{id}, name{name}, v{v}, fmt_auto(false) {}
  friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, const my_length &l) {
    out << l.id << "/" << l.name << " : ";
    if (!l.fmt_auto) {
        return out << l.v << "mm";
    } else {
        if (l.v<10)
            return out << l.v << "mm";
        else if (l.v<1000)
            return out << double(l.v)/10 << "cm";
        else if (l.v<1000000)
            return out << double(l.v)/1000 << "m";
        else
            return out << double(l.v)/1000000 << "km";
    }
  }
  void set_fmt_auto(bool b) {fmt_auto = b;}
};

bool need_fmt_auto(int x) {
  return (x%2) != 0;
}

int main() {
  std::vector<my_length> lengths;
  my_length l{0, "a", 1};
  lengths.push_back(l);
  uint64_t val = 17;
  for (int i=1; i<10; i++) {
    my_length l{i, std::string(1, 'a'+i), val};
    lengths.push_back(l);
    val *= 10;
  }
  for (int i=0; i<lengths.size(); i++) {
    if (need_fmt_auto(i)) {
        lengths[i].set_fmt_auto(true);
        std::cout << "fmt_auto: ";
    }
    std::cout << lengths[i] << "\n";
  }
}
```

Comment: What's the purpose of this class? Once it's initialized you can't even access  `v`, just switch `fmt_auto`. In which context would one want to create an instance? Why not just use a function `std::string length_with_unit(uint64_t v, bool fmt_auto=false)` or something similar?

Comment: I updated my code to clarify the purpose of `my_length`.

Comment: @Yurim Maybe `std::string length_with_unit()` is a good choice. But I think this function can be used only with `my_length`. And << operator does not create string instance unlike `length_with_unit()`, so it makes little advantage on performance. Because of this two reasons, I write this as << operator.

Comment: I still fail to imagine a use case where I would want to create an instance of `my_length` because all I can do with it is to write it to an `std::ostream`. Why would I want to write `my_length l(42,name,567); l.set_fmt_auto(true); std::cout << l;` instead of std::cout << length_with_unit(42, name, 567, true);` or even `std::cout << 42 << '/' << name << " : " << length_with_unit(567, true);`? What's your high-level motivation to write this class?

Comment: @Yurim It is just a toy program. I wrote this code to study c++. I just wondered "my << operator is good enough"

Comment: The lack of whitespace is a major concern here. As a bare minimum, use a blank line between different function definitions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see a number of things that may help you improve your program.

### Gather constants together

The relationship among the numerical values that determine which unit is used and the divisor and the actual unit name is contained within a single function, which is good, but it could be more clear if expressed as a structure.  For example, one could use this:

```
struct Units {
  int limit;
  double divisor;
  std::string name;
};
static const std::array<Units,4> units;
```

Then outside of the class, we supply the values:

```
const std::array<my_length::Units,4> my_length::units = {{
  { 10, 1, "mm" },
  { 1000, 10, "cm" },
  { 1000000, 1000, "m" },
  { 0, 1000000, "km" },
}};
```

This brings things into much closer proximity so that it can be more easily seen and understood.  We can do a little better with C++17 by using `std::string_view` instead of `std::string` for the unit name.

### Isolate concerns

It's usually better to have each function just do one thing.  So insted of deciding on units and *also* printing, I'd suggest splitting those into two, using a private member function:

```
const Units& selectUnit() const {
  auto ret{units.cbegin()};
  if (fmt_auto) {
      while (ret->limit && v >= ret->limit) {
          ++ret; 
      }
  }
  return *ret;
}
```

Now the `operator<<` looks like this:

```
friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, const my_length &l) {
  const Units u{l.selectUnit()};
  return out << l.id << "/" << l.name << " : " 
      << l.v/u.divisor << u.name;
}
```

### Use standard algorithms

The test code starts with this:

```
std::vector<my_length> lengths;
my_length l{0, "a", 1};
lengths.push_back(l);
uint64_t val = 17;
for (int i=1; i<10; i++) {
    my_length l{i, std::string(1, 'a'+i), val};
    lengths.push_back(l);
    val *= 10;
}
```

I'd suggest that one could use [`std::iota`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota) instead.  I'll leave it to you to create the details of that.

### Reconsider the design

Once constructed, there is no capability to do anything with the `my_length` object except to print it.  If all that's needed is printing, then it may be better to use a freestanding function in a namespace instead of an object, as suggested in the comments.  If not, then it makes sense to provide those other operations within the class.

Comment: You beat me to the punch on that one. The only difference I would have made is rather than the units be decided by the class get the user to define the units by allowing a manipulator that is applied first.

Comment: You are right; that would be an improvement.